Неправильное отображение цветов seaborn в DataSpell
Почему в DataSpell цвета показываются неправильно, в другой гамме?
В Jupyter Notebook таких проблем нет.
data = {
    'month':['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'],
    'week1':[6,10,12,14,17],
    'week2':[8,12,13,14,18],
    'week3':[9,11,14,16,20],
    'week4':[10,15,10,17,22]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('month',inplace=True)
sns.heatmap(df,cmap='rocket',annot=True)
plt.show()




датасет свой в вопросе приведите. и код должен быть текстом.
